# IBM Module I Algorithm does not give me different probabilities at different number of iterations

Tags: python, iteration, pseudocode, machine-translation

I am trying to code the IBM Modele using its pseudo-code
[image: This is the pseudo-code that is helping me]

And I believe my code should work but for different iteration numbers the output is printing the same and I have no idea why this is happening.

```
sentence_pairs = [
(["Bugün", "dersimiz", "var"], ["Today","we","have","lecture"]),
(["Yarın", "dersimiz", "yok"], ["Tomarrow","we","dont","have","lecture"])]

e_vocab = []
f_vocab = []

for e_sentence, f_sentence in sentence_pairs:
    for e_token in e_sentence:
        if e_token not in e_vocab:
            e_vocab.append(e_token)
    for f_token in f_sentence:
        if f_token not in f_vocab:
            f_vocab.append(f_token)

def IBM_Model(num_iterations):
t = {}
for e in e_vocab:
    t[e] = {}
    for f in f_vocab:
        t[e][f] = 1.0 / len(f_vocab)

while(num_iterations > 0):
    num_iterations -= 1
    count = {}
    total = {}
    for e in e_vocab:
        count[e] = {}
        for f in f_vocab:
            count[e][f] = 0.0  #for all e,f
            total[f] = 0.0 #for all f

    for (e_sentence, f_sentence) in sentence_pairs:
        s_total = {}
        for e in e_sentence:
            s_total[e] = 0
            for f in f_sentence:
                s_total[e] += t[e][f]

        for e in e_sentence:
            for f in f_sentence:
                count[e][f] += ( t[e][f] / s_total[e] )
                total[f] += ( t[e][f] / s_total[e] )

    for f in f_vocab:
        for e in e_vocab:
            t[e][f] = count[e][f] / total[f]

    print(t)
IBM_Model(10)
```

But IBM_Model(10) is giving the same result as IBM_Model(100) which does not make sense and I think the results are wrong as well

[image: IBM_Model(10)]

[image: IBM_Model(100)]

Both are the same

Comment: Not encouraging you to "cheat" but here's a sample implementation of a working EM algorithm for IBM model 1 https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/translate/ibm1.html

Comment: And for the brave, here's some another implementation https://github.com/LxMLS/lxmls-toolkit/blob/master/lxmls/big_data_em/emstep.py

Answer (score 2):

I don't know anything about your code, I haven't studied it closely.

But I spent the last thirty minutes to re-implement the pseudo-code, because it seems interesting.

I made it working and more iterations do seem make it more accurate.

```
import json
from functools import reduce
from itertools import product
from operator import iconcat

def IBM_Model(sentence_pairs, iterations):
    f_sentences, e_sentences = zip(*sentence_pairs)
    e_vocab = set(reduce(iconcat, e_sentences, []))
    f_vocab = set(reduce(iconcat, f_sentences, []))
    n = 1 / len(f_vocab)
    t = {e: {f: n for f in f_vocab} for e in e_vocab}
    
    for _ in range(iterations):
        count = {e: {f: 0 for f in f_vocab} for e in e_vocab}
        total = {f: 0 for f in f_vocab}
        for f_sentence, e_sentence in sentence_pairs:
            s_total = {e: sum(t[e][f] for f in f_sentence) for e in e_sentence}
            for e, f in product(e_sentence, f_sentence):
                n = t[e][f] / s_total[e]
                count[e][f] += n
                total[f] += n
        
        for e, f in product(e_vocab, f_vocab):
            t[e][f] = count[e][f] / total[f]
    
    return t

sentence_pairs = [
(["Bugün", "dersimiz", "var"], ["Today","we","have","lecture"]),
(["Yarın", "dersimiz", "yok"], ["Tomarrow","we","dont","have","lecture"])]

print(json.dumps(IBM_Model(sentence_pairs, 10), ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
print(json.dumps(IBM_Model(sentence_pairs, 100), ensure_ascii=False, indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
    "Tomarrow": {
        "Yarın": 0.29771444692521004,
        "Bugün": 0.0,
        "dersimiz": 0.0016055740025677433,
        "var": 0.0,
        "yok": 0.29771444692521004
    },
    "lecture": {
        "Yarın": 0.13485703538319327,
        "Bugün": 0.20872809119156158,
        "dersimiz": 0.33218328132638186,
        "var": 0.20872809119156158,
        "yok": 0.13485703538319327
    },
    "we": {
        "Yarın": 0.13485703538319327,
        "Bugün": 0.20872809119156158,
        "dersimiz": 0.33218328132638186,
        "var": 0.20872809119156158,
        "yok": 0.13485703538319327
    },
    "have": {
        "Yarın": 0.13485703538319327,
        "Bugün": 0.20872809119156158,
        "dersimiz": 0.33218328132638186,
        "var": 0.20872809119156158,
        "yok": 0.13485703538319327
    },
    "dont": {
        "Yarın": 0.29771444692521004,
        "Bugün": 0.0,
        "dersimiz": 0.0016055740025677433,
        "var": 0.0,
        "yok": 0.29771444692521004
    },
    "Today": {
        "Yarın": 0.0,
        "Bugün": 0.37381572642531513,
        "dersimiz": 0.00023900801571887713,
        "var": 0.37381572642531513,
        "yok": 0.0
    }
}
{
    "Tomarrow": {
        "Yarın": 0.29999999999999993,
        "Bugün": 0.0,
        "dersimiz": 1.7345987642698527e-26,
        "var": 0.0,
        "yok": 0.29999999999999993
    },
    "lecture": {
        "Yarın": 0.13333333333333333,
        "Bugün": 0.20833333333333331,
        "dersimiz": 0.3333333333333333,
        "var": 0.20833333333333331,
        "yok": 0.13333333333333333
    },
    "we": {
        "Yarın": 0.13333333333333333,
        "Bugün": 0.20833333333333331,
        "dersimiz": 0.3333333333333333,
        "var": 0.20833333333333331,
        "yok": 0.13333333333333333
    },
    "have": {
        "Yarın": 0.13333333333333333,
        "Bugün": 0.20833333333333331,
        "dersimiz": 0.3333333333333333,
        "var": 0.20833333333333331,
        "yok": 0.13333333333333333
    },
    "dont": {
        "Yarın": 0.29999999999999993,
        "Bugün": 0.0,
        "dersimiz": 1.7345987642698527e-26,
        "var": 0.0,
        "yok": 0.29999999999999993
    },
    "Today": {
        "Yarın": 0.0,
        "Bugün": 0.37499999999999994,
        "dersimiz": 4.8725804122518806e-36,
        "var": 0.37499999999999994,
        "yok": 0.0
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, IBM Modules and Machine Translation is a really interesting topics. You're giving different sentences in different languages (more than one if you want to), and writing an algorithm that can check the words between sentences and find relations between them giving you the probability of which English word means which Turkish or French word
By the way, I solve the problem, it was a really simple mistake in my code, "return t" at the end should be in the "for f in f_vocab:" part so that it can return iteration amount times not just once.

Comment: Great job on the EM implementation! BTW, making number of iteration large enough will make the probabilities converge (to be stable and not change as much).